# Video playing beside the 3d viewport

Tags: video

I am trying to create a lego version of a video however I can't find a way to have a video playing beside it in real time. I have tried having the video in the 3d viewport but that had a lot of lag and was constantly out of sync, so I was wondering if there is a way to play a video beside the 3d viewport, in a separate tab.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I remember doing something similar myself - as I wanted my animation to match a video clip, so I used it as a reference.

Personally, I was able to set it as a background image, then work on top of it with it being semi-transparent.

If you find it's lagging a bit when you do this, try downsampling your video if you can. If you use a smaller video that's more lightweight, you'll find it runs smoother.

Try lowering the resolution, frame rate or use a smaller codec (.mp4 instead of .mov, for example).

Apart from that, try opening a video in the UV image editor. Just be sure to raise the number of Frames in the N tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I opened the video in the UV editor and it helped a lot, however there is no sound when I play the video, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @RandomBlenderUser, I'm not sure if sound can be played this way. Are you able to add subtitles or otherwise work around this?